# BASH, create a script to execute a query and append the sorted data in an .htm file

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, bash, append

I want to create a script that executes a prepared statement in the local DB.
All the returned data must be sorted and saved in a specific .htm file.

The script must be able to run every hour and replace the existing htm.

The script will be executed by bin/bash hourly, in an Ubuntu machine.

So far I have this script, it wasn't created by me. Maybe we could modify it so it can run every 60 minutes.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javolution.text.TextBuilder;

public class ClanList
{
       private TextBuilder _clanList = new TextBuilder();

       public ClanList(int type)
       {
               loadFromDB(type);
       }

       private void loadFromDB(int type)
       {
               Connection con = null;
               int stpoint = 0;
               int results = 20;
               String castlename = "";
               String allystatus = "";
               String leadername = "";
               for (int count = 1; count != type; count++)
               {
                       stpoint += 20;
               }

               try
               {
                       con = L2DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
                       PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT clan_id, clan_name, ally_name, leader_id, lan_level, reputation_score, hasCastle, ally_id FROM clan_data ORDER BY `clan_level` desc Limit " + stpoint + ", " + results);
                       ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
                       int pos = 0;

                       while (result.next())
                       {
                               int clanid = result.getInt("leader_id");
                               String clan = result.getString("clan_name");
                               String ally = result.getString("ally_name");
                               int clanleader = result.getInt("leader_id");
                               int clanlevel = result.getInt("clan_level");
                               int reputation = result.getInt("reputation_score");
                               int hascastle = result.getInt("hasCastle");
                               int allyid = result.getInt("ally_id");
                               if (allyid != 0)
                               {
                                       if (allyid == clanid)
                                               allystatus = "Alliance Leader";
                                       allystatus = "Affiliated Clan";
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                       allystatus = "-";
                                       ally = "[no-ally]";
                               }
                               if (hascastle != 0)
                               {
                                       PreparedStatement statement2 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM castle WHERE id=" + hascastle);
                                       ResultSet result2 = statement2.executeQuery();
                                       if (result2.next())
                                               castlename = result2.getString("name");
                                       result2.close();
                                       statement2.close();
                               }
                               else
                                       castlename = "[none]";
                               PreparedStatement statement3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT char_name FROM characters WHERE harId=" + clanleader);
                               ResultSet result3 = statement3.executeQuery();

                               if (result3.next())
                                       leadername = result3.getString("char_name");
                               result3.close();
                               statement3.close();
                               pos++;
                               addClanToList(pos, clan, ally, leadername, clanlevel, reputation, castlename, allystatus);
                       }
                       result.close();
                       statement.close();
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                       e.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally
               {
                       L2DatabaseFactory.close(con);
               }
       }

       private void addClanToList(int pos, String clan, String ally, String leadername, int clanlevel, int reputation, String castlename, String allystatus)
       {
               _clanList.append("<table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 width=760>");
               _clanList.append("<tr>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=5></td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=20>" + pos + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=90>" + clan + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=90>" + ally + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=85>" + leadername + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=45 align=center>" + clanlevel + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=70 align=center>" + reputation + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=50 align=center>" + castlename + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=70 align=center>" + allystatus + "</td>");
               _clanList.append("<td FIXWIDTH=5></td>");
               _clanList.append("</tr>");
               _clanList.append("</table>");
               _clanList.append("<img src=\"L2UI.Squaregray\" width=\"740\" height=\"1\">");
       }

       public String loadClanList()
       {
               return _clanList.toString();
       }
}
```

I'm new to programming, therefore I don't know what language can make this easier.

Comment: That's not a script that's java source code. You can compile that and run it however often you want if that does what you need.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is part of a program that needs to be compiled. A lineage 2 server emulator. But it does not do what i want. At least not exactly.